# MySQL insert isn't inserting

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i'm having an issue while writing registration Form, database should be connected(it isn't throwing any errors) but it just isn't saying anything so i don't know how to solve this.
it isn't completed yet but i need to solve the database issue in the first place right now, i'd be really appreciated if you help me

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      include "_DB.php";
      if($_POST["btnODESLAT"])
      {
        $db = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=" .dbserver. ";dbname=" .dbname,dbuser,dbpass,
    array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
    )
  );
        $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);
        $pass2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass2"]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
        $nick = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nick"]);
        $sex = htmlspecialchars($_POST["sex"]);
        if($pass == $pass2)
        {
          $check_nick = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblOSOBA WHERE NICK = '$nick'");
            $check2_nick = $check_nick->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($check2_nick as $check3_nick)
            {
                $check_final_nick = $check3_nick["COUNT(*)"];    
            }
          }
          if($check_final_nick == "0")               
          {
              $insert_user = "INSERT INTO `tblOSOBA`(`ID_OSOBA`, `NICK`, `HESLO`, `POHLAVI_ID`, `EMAIL`, `POHLAVI_ID`) VALUES (NULL, '$nick', '".md5($pass)."', '".$_POST["sex"]."', '$email', $sex)";
              $db->exec($insert_user);

              $final= $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblOSOBA WHERE NICK='".$_POST["nick"]."'");
              $results = $final->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach($results as $result)
              { 
                $_SESSION["id_user"] = $result["ID_OSOBA"]; 
              }            
              $_SESSION["login"] = "101010"; 
              }
              else{
              echo "huehue";
              }
      }



echo "
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

          <FORM id='sidebar' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'>
                     <INPUT type='text' placeholder='Nick' name='nick'><BR>
                     <INPUT type='password' placeholder='Pass' name='pass'><BR>
           <INPUT type='password' placeholder='Pass' name='pass2'><BR>
           <INPUT type='text' placeholder='Email' name='email'><BR>
                     <p>Pohlaví<p><BR>
                     <INPUT type='radio' name='sex' value='2'>Muž<BR>
                     <INPUT type='radio' name='sex' value='1'>Žena<BR>    
                     <INPUT type='submit' name='btnODESLAT' value='Odeslat'>                
          </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
";
?>
```

Comment: Dreamweaver says there aren't any syntax errors, but i don't have it connected to ftp. in pspad there aren't any errors as well and every bracket should be okay

Comment: Can you be more specific on the situation? Can you write to the database? What happens if you echo our your vars, do they have data? Are there any errors in your log file?

Comment: i can write to the database directly in PMA, but it's not writing from the file, i'm really a beginner, so i don't have any log files

Comment: There's alot more built in php functions which specialize in debugging. Never rely purely on your IDE

Comment: It always worked out till now i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicated a column.

```
          $insert_user = "INSERT INTO `tblOSOBA`(`ID_OSOBA`, `NICK`, `HESLO`, `POHLAVI_ID`, `EMAIL`, `POHLAVI_ID`) VALUES (NULL, '$nick', '".md5($pass)."', '".$_POST["sex"]."', '$email', $sex)";
          $db->exec($insert_user);
```

Should be only 1 instance of POHLAVI_ID

```
          $insert_user = "INSERT INTO `tblOSOBA`(`ID_OSOBA`, `NICK`, `HESLO`, `EMAIL`, `POHLAVI_ID`) VALUES (NULL, '$nick', '".md5($pass)."', '$email', $sex)";
          $db->exec($insert_user);
```

By the way, PDO has an in-built method to get the last insert ID. You can replace this entire block

```
          $final= $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblOSOBA WHERE NICK='".$_POST["nick"]."'");
          $results = $final->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          foreach($results as $result)
          { 
            $_SESSION["id_user"] = $result["ID_OSOBA"]; 
          }
```

with:

```
$_SESSION['id_user'] = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Thank you, I've overseen it, but it still isn't writing into DB :/

Comment: Can we please see the results of adding this code after your `$db->exec($insert_user);` line: `var_dump( $db->errorInfo() );`

Comment: Thank you, i'll surely use it, i'd give you a rep but i can't give it just yet, but it seems to work now when i erased that pointless nick & email check which was pretty shabby

Answer (score 0):

I've erased that no working Email & Nick check and it seems to work. I don't know what that error was but it seems to work now

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      include "_DB.php";
      if($_POST["btnODESLAT"])
      {
        $db = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=" .dbserver. ";dbname=" .dbname,dbuser,dbpass,
    array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
    )
  );
        $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);
        $pass2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass2"]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
        $nick = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nick"]);
        $sex = htmlspecialchars($_POST["sex"]);
        if($pass == $pass2)
        {
              $insert_user = "INSERT INTO `tblOSOBA`(`ID_OSOBA`, `NICK`, `HESLO`, `EMAIL`,`POHLAVI_ID`) VALUES (NULL, '$nick', '".md5($pass)."', '$email', $sex)";
              $db->query($insert_user);

              $final= $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblOSOBA WHERE NICK='".$_POST["nick"]."'");
              $results = $final->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach($results as $result)
              { 
                $_SESSION["id_user"] = $result["ID_OSOBA"]; 
              }            
              $_SESSION["login"] = "101010"; 
              }
              else{
              echo "huehue";
              }
      }



echo "
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

          <FORM id='sidebar' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'>
                     <INPUT type='text' placeholder='Nick' name='nick'><BR>
                     <INPUT type='password' placeholder='Pass' name='pass'><BR>
           <INPUT type='password' placeholder='Pass' name='pass2'><BR>
           <INPUT type='text' placeholder='Email' name='email'><BR>
                     <p>Pohlaví<p><BR>
                     <INPUT type='radio' name='sex' value='2'>Muž<BR>
                     <INPUT type='radio' name='sex' value='1'>Žena<BR>    
                     <INPUT type='submit' name='btnODESLAT' value='Odeslat'>                
          </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
";
?>
```